# How to change the Xcode theme to your liking?

Tags: xcode, themes

How to change Xcode Theme?
I don't want to use the basic theme anymore.
I'm using imac, and I want the exact way.

Comment: Lisa did you get your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First, you have to download the theme. Only '.xccolortheme' format files are possible.
   If you search "xcode them download" on Google, you'll find a lot.
2. You must enter the terminal and enter the command.

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/
mkdir FontAndColorThemes
open .
```

3. Put the downloaded file in this folder.
4. Open Xcode and enter Editor -> Theme to see your downloaded theme.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the preferences from the the Xcode menu (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) and use the **Themes** tab. So you can set any kind of style you like (predefined, downloaded or completly custom)

[image: Demo]